# Send the value back from pop up portlet to parent portlet

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet, alloy-ui

1. The parent portlet has a form which I fill but do not submit yet.
2. Then from this parent portlet I click a link to open a pop up portlet where I fill the the form in the pop up and submit the value.
3. This value should now be available in the parent portlet. But without refresh the value is not available in the parent portlet.
4. So I write the logic to refresh the parent portlet on the pop up submit using ajax and the value becomes available in the parent portlet.
5. But the problem is the form in the parent portlet gets cleared and I have to again re-fill the form.

So how to preserve this parent form values which are yet to be submitted? Or is there a way to make the pop up portlet value available in the parent portlet without refreshing the parent portlet?

The code for parent portlet:

```
<aui:form action="<%= editURL %>" method="POST" name="fm">
     <aui:fieldset>
        <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirect %>" />


         <aui:input name="name" />

         <aui:input name="acronym" />

         <aui:input name="url" />

         <aui:select  showEmptyOption="<%= true %>">

              // Want to make the values added from pop up available here

         </aui:select>

         <%
             String portletId = (String) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);
             String portletNamespace = PortalUtil.getPortletNamespace(portletId);
         %>

         <c:set var="portletNameSpaceVal" value="<%=portletNamespace%>" />

         <liferay-portlet:renderURL 
             var="addURL" windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString() %>"
             portletName="name">
             <liferay-portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/person/edit_person_popup.jsp"/>
         </liferay-portlet:renderURL>

         <c:set var="portletURL" value="<%=addURL%>" />

         <aui:a href="#" onClick="${portletNameSpaceVal}showPopup('${portletURL}')"><liferay-ui:icon image="add"/></aui:a> // this link triggers the pop up


         <aui:select label="Country" name="countryCode" showEmptyOption="<%= true %>">

              <%
                 for (Country country : countries) {
             %>

             <%
                 }
             %>

         </aui:select>




     </aui:fieldset>

     <aui:button-row>
         <aui:button type="submit" />

         <aui:button onClick="<%= viewURL %>"  type="cancel" />
     </aui:button-row>
 </aui:form>


 <aui:script>
     function <portlet:namespace />showPopup(url) {

         var url = url;

             Liferay.Util.openWindow(
                 {
                     dialog: {
                         cache: false,
                         width:800,
                         modal: true,
                         centered: true
                     },
                     id: 'popUpId',                
                     uri: url
                 }
             );
     }

 </aui:script>

 <aui:script>
     Liferay.provide(window, 'refreshPortlet', function() {
         var curPortlet = '#p_p_id<portlet:namespace/>';
         Liferay.Portlet.refresh(curPortlet);
     },
     ['aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
     );
 </aui:script>

 <aui:script>
     Liferay.provide(window, 'closePopup', function(dialogId) {
         var A = AUI();
         var dialog = Liferay.Util.Window.getById(dialogId);
         dialog.destroy();
     },
     ['liferay-util-window']
     );
 </aui:script>
```

Then I have the pop up portlet.

```
<aui:form action="<%= editURL %>" method="POST" name="fm" onSubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <aui:fieldset>

        <aui:input name="name" />

        <aui:input name="url" />

        <aui:input name="address" />

    </aui:fieldset>

    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="submit" />

        <aui:button name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>

    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>

<aui:script use="aui-base,aui-form-validator,aui-io-request">
    AUI().use('aui-base','aui-form-validator','aui-io-request',function(A){
        var rules = {
              <portlet:namespace/>name: {
                required: true
              },

              <portlet:namespace/>url: {
                url: true
              },

              <portlet:namespace/>address: {
                required: true
              },
          };

        var fieldStrings = {
            <portlet:namespace/>name: {
                required: 'The Name field is required.'
              },

              <portlet:namespace/>address: {
                required: 'The Address field is required.'
              },
        };

        new A.FormValidator({
            boundingBox: '#<portlet:namespace/>fm',
            fieldStrings: fieldStrings,
            rules: rules,
            showAllMessages:true,
            on: {
                    validateField: function(event) {
                     },
                    validField: function(event) {
                   },
                    errorField: function(event) {
                    },
                    submitError: function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
                    },
                    submit: function(event) {
                        var A = AUI();
                        var url = '<%=editURL.toString()%>';

                        A.io.request(
                            url,
                            {
                                method: 'POST',
                                form: {id: '<portlet:namespace/>fm'},
                                on: {
                                    success: function() {
                                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().refreshPortlet();
                                        Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popUpId');                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                       );
                   }
                }
          });
    });

</aui:script>




<aui:script use="aui-base">
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>cancel').on('click', function(event) {
        Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popUpId);
    });
</aui:script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I think you can do:

1. You can pass data from the Server in JSON format.
2. Fetch that in `success` method
3. Transfer the data to a parent javascript function
4. run the method in the parent to update the `<aui:select>`.

Some sample code in the pop-up's success method:

```
success: function(responseData) {
    // refresh method removed
    // get the responseData as JSON or something from the server
    Liferay.Util.getOpener().updateDataFromPopUp("JSON-data-passed");
    Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('popUpId');                                        
}
```

And in parent:

```
<aui:script>
     Liferay.provide(window, 'updateDataFromPopUp', function(jsonDataFromPopUp) {
         // do something with the data here
        }
     );
 </aui:script>
```

There may be other ways but this is what I could think of right now.

---

A Suggestion:

You can have all the functions in one `<aui:script></aui:script>` instead of having this multiple times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am new to liferay and do not have so much expertise. As I understand I have to use resourceURL and define the method serveResource to get this done. But since my form has actionURL in the popup which calls the appropriate method where the input is inserted into the database as well. So how can I use resourceURL and actionURL together?

Comment: did you try giving the resourceURL inside HTML form's action attribute?

Comment: Yes when I provide the resourceURL in form's action attribute the serveResource method is called. Then how to call the actionURL method now? Calling from inside serveResource or should the logic of that insert method also go inside this serveResource method?

Comment: Since as it is you are not using the action-phase you can move the insert logic to serve-resource method and then return the output in JSON or in whatever way you want. Thanks

Comment: In the parent the JSON data is transferred but I don't know how to update the select box. <aui:script>
     Liferay.provide(window, 'updateDataFromPopUp', function(id, name) {
         // I get the id and name here. But don't know how to update selectbox
A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>Id').get('options').set().......
        }
     );
 </aui:script>

Comment: That's the realm of plain javascript, you may find many options how to do it in jQuery and `aui` does not seem to be different. Just search for the string `how to populate dropdown with json data` in google and the top answers you would find would be of stackoverflow. I can update but am a little short of time right now.

Comment: A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>Id').append('<option value="'+ personId +'">'+ name +'</option>');
        A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>Id').set('value',personId);
this way worked.